How to Render the JSX Returned by an Async Function Called From Inside Array.Map() in React?
In my React application, I am calling an async function that renders a JSX from inside array.map(), but nothing is being rendered. I confirmed that the function is being called properly.
I suspect that there is something related to the rendering being executed before the async function returns its result, but I do not understand why this would happen if the async function is using await in its internal calls
<div>
   {
      gallery.map((image) => 
         {renderImage(image, 'vegan-mundi-gallery')}
   )}
</div>


I tried wrapping the function that generates the JSX inside a React Fragment (<></>) as in the snippet below, but then I get the error "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise])".
{
   gallery.map((image) => (
   // The react fragment below is generating the error Objects are not valid as a React child    (found: [object Promise]) - which reinforced the idea that the async function haven’t returned its result by the time of the rendering
      <>
         {renderImage(image, 'vegan-mundi-gallery')}
      </>
   )
)}

Does anyone can help with this?
This is my complete code:
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Gallery (){

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [gallery, setGallery] = useState([]);

    useEffect( ()=> {
    // some code that gets the gallery array from an API call and handles the isLoading state 
    } , []);

    const renderImage = async(item, bucket) => {

        const photo = item.PHOTO;
        const data = await fetch(`http://1.1.1.1:4000/s3/${bucket}/${photo}`);
        const preSignedUrl = await data.json();
        console.log(preSignedUrl) // I can see the preSignedUrl in the console, so the async call worked!

        return (
            <figure>
                <div>
                    <img key={photo}
                        src={`${preSignedUrl}`}
                    />
                </div>
                <figcaption>{item.LABEL}</figcaption>
            </figure>
        )
    }


    if (isLoading){
        return(<p>loading...</p>);
    }
    else {

        return (
                <div>
                    {
                        gallery.map((image) => 
                                {renderImage(image, 'vegan-mundi-gallery')}

                    )}
                </div>
          )
    }
}

I checked ChatGPT, and it suggested exactly what I have done with the <></>.

I'd recommend doing all of the async calls inside useEffect, and saving the results in state, so you can avoid async calls when you render.

Thanks for pointing me the right direction, JW. I was struggling to figure out how to implement it, and then @Dileepa Mabulage provided the solution!

Better use useEffects to handle this situation.
const [gallery, setGallery] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
        // Simulate API call to get gallery array
        const fetchGallery = async () => {
            const galleryData = [
                { PHOTO: 'photo1.jpg', LABEL: 'Label 1' },
                { PHOTO: 'photo2.jpg', LABEL: 'Label 2' },
            ];
            setGallery(galleryData);
        };

        fetchGallery();
    }, []);

for fetching images
const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);


useEffect(() => {
        const fetchImages = async () => {
            const fetchedImages = await Promise.all(
                gallery.map(async (item) => {
                    const photo = item.PHOTO;
                    const response = await fetch(`http://1.1.1.1:4000/s3/bucketname/${photo}`);
                    const preSignedUrl = await response.json();
                    return { ...item, url: preSignedUrl };
                })
            );
            setImages(fetchedImages);
            setIsLoading(false);
        };

        if (gallery.length > 0) {
            fetchImages();
        }
    }, [gallery]);

if (isLoading) {
        return (<p>loading...</p>);
    } else {
        return (
            <div>
                {images.map((image) => (
                    <figure key={image.PHOTO}>
                        <div>
                            <img src={image.url} alt={image.LABEL} />
                        </div>
                        <figcaption>{image.LABEL}</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }

